# node.js server errror on two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js

I am trying to submit form with two dimensional array fields on post request in node.js. But it is not giving correct array on server side. I receive one dimensional array containing all values.

Here it is form

```
<form method="post" action="/add">
<div id="row1">
    <input name="type[][serial]" type="text">
    <input name="type[][desc]" type="text">
    <select name="type[][name]">
        <option value="VAL1">VAL1</option>
        <option value="VAL2">VAL2</option>
        <option value="VAL3">VAL3</option>
    </select>
    <input name="type[][maker]" type="text">
</div>
<div id="row2">
    <input name="type[][serial]" type="text">
    <input name="type[][desc]" type="text">
    <select name="type[][name]">
        <option value="VAL1">VAL1</option>
        <option value="VAL2">VAL2</option>
        <option value="VAL3">VAL3</option>
    </select>
    <input name="type[][maker]" type="text">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am using express 4 with bodyparser defined in my application.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

when i try to access value of array like this

```
var hd =  req.body.type;
var serial =  hd[0]['serial'];
```

then i get error value undefined.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('<form method="post" action="/add">\
    <div id="row1">\
        <input name="type[][serial]" type="text">\
        <input name="type[][desc]" type="text">\
        <select name="type[][name]">\
            <option value="VAL1">VAL1</option>\
            <option value="VAL2">VAL2</option>\
            <option value="VAL3">VAL3</option>\
        </select>\
        <input name="type[][maker]" type="text">\
    </div>\
    <div id="row2">\
        <input name="type[][serial]" type="text">\
        <input name="type[][desc]" type="text">\
        <select name="type[][name]">\
            <option value="VAL1">VAL1</option>\
            <option value="VAL2">VAL2</option>\
            <option value="VAL3">VAL3</option>\
        </select>\
        <input name="type[][maker]" type="text">\
    </div>\
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">\
    </form>\
  ');
});

app.post('/add', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body.type[0]['serial']);
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Then after pressing Submit something like this is displayed in the browser: `["asdf","fdsa"]`

Comment: On which version you try this? My version of node v0.10.31 and body-parser v1.0.0. and i am still unable to get data.

Comment: node v0.10.30 and brand new `npm install express body-parser`, so that means express 4.9.8 and body-parser 1.9.0 as of this writing.

Comment: There was a problem in `body-parser` i just updated it and now it is giving this output. `[{"name":["LCD","MotherBoard"],"serial":["12345D","12345D"],"desc":["19\"",".77"],"maker":["Hp","DELL"]}]` but i want this this kind of output `[{"serial":"12345D","name":"LCD","desc":".77","maker":"Hp"},{"serial":"12345D","name":"LCD","desc":".77","maker":"Hp"}]` how can i get this?

Comment: I don't think there is any intelligent way to get output like that using the syntax you're currently using. You'd have to specify the index so that the parser knows how to properly assign the properties to arbitrary objects, something like `types[0][serial]` in the first row and `types[1][serial]` in the second, etc.

Comment: got it. Now i write jquery function that do this. Thanks '        $("div.row").each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('input[name="type[][name]"]').attr('name', 'type[' + i  + '][name]');
            $(this).find('input[name="type[][serial]"]').attr('name', 'type[' + i  + '][serial]');
            $(this).find('input[name="type[][desc]"]').attr('name', 'type[' + i  + '][desc]');
            $(this).find('input[name="type[][maker]"]').attr('name', 'type[' + i  + '][maker]');
        });'

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem in code. I was accessing and parsing values incorrectly.